# SQL Server Management Studio - Table Designer

Tags: sql-server, designer

I've seen a few posts about adding the description property to the table designer for 2008, but what about 2014 (or, 2016 for that matter)?

This is incredibly useful and I'm shocked that it's not already a standard feature - to add viewable properties like description, identity, etc.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I check out and I give you this tow Links.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177173.aspx
http://codebyjoshua.blogspot.com/2014/02/add-column-description-property-to.html

I hope that it could be usefull.

Comment: Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on *How do I write a good answer?*. Take note of the topic *Provide context for links*: `Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.`

Comment: Thanks so much for the links. Unfortunately, they don't work for SQL Management Studio 2014.